# Change the width of horizontal scroll bar

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

How can I change the width of horizontal scroll bar. I want to reduce the width than the div size. (do not want 100% width)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using a customisation of the `end` and `start` scrollbar track pieces.

Effectively, you make the start and end piece *invisible* and set a large margin on it, and it will reduce the width of the available scrollbar to the size you want.

You can modify the position and width by changing the `margin`s on the `start` and `end` piece.

See the following demonstration:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
}

.inner {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}

.inner::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 5px;
}
  
.inner::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: blue;
}

.inner::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:end {
  margin-right: 50px; 
}

.inner::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:start {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner">
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
    <div>Hello</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It works. But I have one more question. If I try to show the shadow it takes 100% width.

Comment: @Dinu If you have a different question, it's probably sensible to post that separately as it's not directly related to your first one

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
th, td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div style="overflow-x:auto; width:50%">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
      <th>Points</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Adam</td>
      <td>Johnson</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
      <td>67</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```